# UITextField não exibe teclado (IOS / Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, teclado, uitextfield

Meu campo (UITextField) não exibe o teclado da aplicação quando é selecionado através do simulador.

Comment: No aparelho ou simulador?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Melhora sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator

Comment: No simulador Paulo Rodrigues.

Comment: Renan, peço desculpas pela pergunta não tão específica e agradeço pelo link informado. Problema resolvido ao mudar a configuração do IOS Simulator > Keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No simulador, de forma imediata você pode utilizar `Command + k` para mostrar ou esconder o teclado.

Por padrão ele vem escondido porque a opção **Connect Hardware Keyboard** no menu `Hardware > Keyboard` está selecionada, então o seu padrão de inserção de dados vai ser pelo teclado físico do *Mac*.

Você pode desmarcar esta opção para sempre exibir o teclado do simulador, mas isto irá invalidar o seu teclado físico e nenhuma tecla terá ação, que às vezes é útil para ganhar agilidade na digitação.